# How to iterate each record in a group

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, group-by, counter

I want to add a column that iterates a value for a group. The dataframe is pre-sorted as I need:

```
Index :|: GRP BY Col :|: New Col:|  
0     :|: 1          :|: 0      :|
1     :|: 1          :|: 1      :|   
2     :|: 1          :|: 2      :|   
3     :|: 2          :|: 0      :|   
4     :|: 2          :|: 1      :|
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need [`cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'GRP BY Col':[1,1,1,2,2]})
df['New Col'] = df.groupby('GRP BY Col').cumcount()
print (df)
   GRP BY Col  New Col
0           1        0
1           1        1
2           1        2
3           2        0
4           2        1
```